# jQuery store or transfer elements of a select (drop down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select input that is populated by an sql query. I am trying to do the following, due to the sequence of events that occurs for the webpage

1) Populate the select list 
2) Empty the div containing the select list
3) Re-use the select list in a new div that is appended to the html

I never leave the page but I do destroy the select element. I want to be able to store the select element for use later. I thought it would be as easy as:

```
var teamList; 

$('.otherSelector').on('change',function(){
  $.post(url, {x:x},function(data){ 
    teamList = $('#teamList'); //actual select input

            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                var option = $('<option/>');
                option.attr('value', key)
                      .html(val)
                      .appendTo(teamList);
            });
  }
```

After the teamList is populated, a button is clicked and it is removed via empty(). I thought however that the data would remain in the variable teamList because I am not altering the variable when removing the DOM element. Maybe I am just storing it or calling it wrong? I am trying to call it like this:

```
$('.selector').on('click',function(){
  var newStuff = '<form>'+
                 '<input name = "test" type = "text">'+
                 teamList+
                 '........etc
$('html').append(newStuff);
```

In the form element i see [object Object] instead of the drop-down list.

Any help is appreciated.

---

My own answer:

teamList.prop("outerHTML") actually

Thanks to Patrick Evans

Answer (score 1):

That is because `teamList` is a dom object. By default when doing string concatenation of an object it will print out `[Object object]` and not the contents of the object, in this case the html text making up the dom element.

To re-add the select to the form use jQuery's `append` function.

```
$('.selector').on('click',function(){
   var form = $('<form><input name = "test" type = "text"></form');
   form.append(teamList);
   $('body').append(form);
});
```

Also note that I changed your `$('html')` to `$('body')` as you shouldn't append content directly to the `<html>` element.

If you do want to do it just with string concatenation you will need to use jQuery's `outerHTML` function which will return the html of the element and its contents

```
$('.selector').on('click',function(){
   var newStuff = '<form>'+
                 '<input name = "test" type = "text">'+
                 teamList[0].outerHTML+
                 '</form>';
   $('body').append(newStuff);
});
```

Comment: Would you say that the difference between your two posted methods is just preference? And what is bad about attaching to html? Thanks!

Comment: .prop("outerHTML") actually

Comment: Because adding content to the `<html>` element directly is invalid html markup. It only works because browsers are forgiving in html markup mistakes. And you are correct it is `prop('outerHTML')`, or get the actual dom element and access `outerHTML`: `teamList[0].outerHTML`